# How to use filter for Tenant and Host at the same time

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have a table where I want to share some entries for all tenants with a `NULL` value for `tenantId` and some specifics `tenantId`. What is the best way to do it with the filter when I want to get the list? I didn't success to find an elegant way to do it without doing something like deactivate the filter `MayHaveTenant` and make the filter in the request `GetAllListAsync()`by myself.

Comment: Why don't you disable MayHaveTenant filter, so you can query all entities.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've done but I'm just surprised that no filter exists to remove "MayHaveTenant" and "MustHaveTenant" themselves and can query NULL tenant Or TenantId == CurrentTenantId().

Comment: what about not using MayHaveTenant filter at all.

Comment: Sure Aaron, I mean I used CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MustHaveTenant, AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant)

Comment: No, people can just read the comments, it's enough.